# Is this a date in February or in March? cal.set(2010, 1, 10)

Tags: java, date, calendar

I have set this calendar in my app:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(2010, 1, 10);
```

I'm using this `SimpleDateFormat` to get the month as a word:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatMonth = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
```

In one class it comes out as **`February`** `10th, 2010`.

In another it comes out as **`March`** `10th, 2010`.

**Which is correct?**

Answer (score 7):

The `month` argument to [Calendar.set()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int,%20int%29) is zero-based, so `1` means `February`. The first behavior is the correct one.

I suspect something in your other class is mistakenly trying to compensate for zero-based month indexes, and that results in an [off-by-one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) error.

Answer (score 3):

The calendar class has constants for months

```
 Calendar.JANUARY
```

for example. You should be using those.

Answer (score 1):

Given all the hassles associated with the JDK date handling, you should really be looking to [use Joda time instead](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). The above code would be rewritten as

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime().withDate(2010,2,10).withTime(12,13,14,0);
```

and represents 10 February 2010 at 12:13:14.000 in UTC. No ambiguity, thread safe and immutable.

You should note that SimpleDateFormat is not thread safe.

Comment: Why does it matter if SimpleDateFormat is not thread safe? Where could that cause a problem for example?

Comment: It would only cause problems when you've declared it as a static or  instance variable so that it's been used among different threads. It's safe if you declare it methodlocal. This has however not much to do with your *actual* problem.

Comment: @kors As BalusC has rightly pointed out SimpleDateFormat is fine to use if you create a new instance within a method every time. Most people don't do this and rely on external static helpers which leads to multiple threads changing it's internal state and you getting spurious results when parsing and formatting dates when the application is under load. This is a problem you are likely to encounter later, so I'm pre-empting a future problem for you and trying to guide you to a better overall solution.